# gcc throws a lot of warnings on an included file

Tags: c, gcc

When I run `make`, I'm getting a warning about the fact that one of my external files has `main` in it. Specifically, I'm including the well-known **[mt19937ar.c](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/CODES/mt19937ar.c)** into my project for utilizing the random number generator. In fact, I'm getting *a lot* of warnings about that file but, seeing as it's the original source code of a well-used program, I'm not apt to touch it.

I don't want to edit that source code but I'm unaware of an alternative solution to get the compiler to  ignore these errors.

Below is the **makefile** that I'm using:

```
TARGET = prog
LIBS = -lm
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -pthread -Wextra -Wall -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wcast-qual -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wconversion -Wunreachable-code

.PHONY: clean all default

default: $(TARGET) clean
all: default

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -Wall $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
```

Comment: A C program can have only one main function. Removing the "library"s main function is your only option.

Comment: Don't be too shy to touch well known original source code, most security problems exist for years in code because no one fells apt to read, understand and modify it. And in 95%-99.9% of the cases, a compiler warnings is or hints to an actual bug, that just has not been triggered yet.

Comment: @BodoThiesen A lot of the errors have to do with conversions to `long unsigned int` from `int` or conversions to `double` from `long unsigned int`. These seem like obvious possible issues- why would the original author ignore that?

Comment: "I don't really understand it, but it works for me"? Many code was written by beginners and then later not fixed. I don't know whether it's the case here, but I wouldn't trust a code with tons of warnings. Also, sometimes code works because of assumptions that have never been guaranteed and later gone wrong. Like int being 2 bytes long - isn't true for decades now, but old code relies on stuff like that. At one time, I took a look at bash's source code, only to believe, I'm to dumb for it. Later it turned out, bash is full of security issues. So it's coder ...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are #including  but then also providing a main method in your actual code, thus leaving you with two main methods, gcc doesn't know which one you want. The file mt19937ar.c is not a library - if you only want to use some of its functions, you'll have to either copy-and-paste them, or edit mt19937ar.c (e.g. commenting out the main method).

Comment: Note that: "1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.". So simply cutting out the functions you need is probably not a great option.

Comment: no, he would have to copy&paste the copyright notice as well.

Answer (score 0):

One way to hack round the error would be to create a `mt19937ar_no_main.c` file:

```
#define main mt19937ar_main
#include "mt19937ar.c"  // Yes, include the .c file
```

Now you can compile `mt19937ar_no_main.c` instead of `mt19937ar.c`. You can still call the original `main()`, if you really want to, with `mt19937ar_main();`.

Also, since I notice your `makefile` compiles `*.c`, you may also rename `mt19937ar.c` to `mt19937ar.c.inc` or the like to prevent it being compiled along with the `mt19937ar_no_main.c` wrapper.

Comment: why not just rename to a .h file and wrap with header guards to keep everything a bit more clean?

Comment: because it's not a header file?

Comment: @ForrestKoch if it gets included by two different files bad things may happen.

Comment: @KenY-N thus the header guards I mentioned, which should be included anyways because there's nothing stopping him from including it in another file.

Comment: header guards prevent troubles from double inclusions of the a header file in the same compilation unit. It has no effect in double inclusions of a header file in separate compilation units. i.e. a.c: #include "x.c" | b.c: #include "x.c" | gcc a.c b.c -o x-conflict -> will spit out error for every function and variable definition in x.c

Comment: Two different C files (translation units), not two different header files.

Comment: @BodoThiesen but this answer involves including a file, so wouldn't it make sense to prevent double inclusions?

Extensions are just convention at the end of the day, so if he's including it, it's effectively a header file.

Comment: @ForrestKoch: OP says he's including the file in his project. He doesn't say he's `#include`ing it in another source file. And even if he is, it's still a bad idea, and not one to be encouraged.

Comment: I misread this answer. I thought `#define main mt19937ar_main
#include "mt19937ar.c"  // Yes, include the .c file` was in his source, not `mt19937ar_no_main.c`.  My bad.

Comment: no problem, we all have some days when we act like noobs :P

Comment: No upvotes on this answer... Can't tell if you guys decided to be for or against it haha